# How to write this code's output to a text file?

Tags: python

I just want all the output in a text file

```
def load_comments(self, mat):


    for item in mat["items"]:
        comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
        author = comment["snippet"]["authorDisplayName"]
        text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]

        if 'replies' in item.keys():
            for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                rauthor = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
                rtext = reply["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
            print("{}".format(rtext))
        print("{}".format(text))
```

When I tried by simply putting >filename.txt while running the code it prints only some lines and not all the lines. But when i try to run it on the console it prints all the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python file output", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Actually the whole code is on https://github.com/srcecde/python-youtube-api. I only want the comment part but the output will be shown in the text file. Can you please help me and check the code once ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output is this part:

```
print("{}".format(text))
```

just replace this with:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write("{}".format(text))
```